# Raspbian Stretch: Opening a browser from CLI and hitting play on a stream automatically

Tags: raspberry-pi, command-line-interface, raspbian

I'm exploring ways to opening a browser on an RPI media center (Kodi/Plex normally) to open and play this website: https://www.ruv.is/sjonvarp/beint?channel=ruv

Normally the RPI boots directly to kodi as a WM. I'm pretty sure I can figure out a script that would kill Kodi, drop to CLI (or boot lightdm) and start firefox/chromium on the specific site.

But I'm not sure about hitting the play button and setting it to fullscreen. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `pyautogui` maybe.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, I'll look into it!